# Mis-alignment of img icon in nav bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an additional icon in my navigation bar, and the main problem is that the icon is not available in the same format as the rest of my social icons, so I have to include it as an img instead of a data-icon within a span tag.

See image below.

[image]

Here is the code snippet comparing the two list items.

```
<li class='c-nav__item c-nav__item--social'>
  <a href='https://github.com/nimblegeek' title='Github' target='_blank' rel='noopener'>
    <span class='c-nav__item__icon' data-icon='ei-sc-github' data-size='m' style="color: white;"></span>
    <span class='u-hidden-visually'>Github</span>
  </a>
</li>

<li class='c-nav__item c-nav__item--social'>
  <img href='https://jonasasihlen.medium.com/' src='https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5968/5968906.png' width="20"
    title='Medium' target='_blank' rel='noopener'>
</li>
```

For some reason the img is "jumping" up a notch and it looks like it's taking up extra padding on top but it seems to be living its own life as an img instead of being included as a div...

[image: github icon nicely aligne]

[image: medium img]

I have tried to remove extra a tags and span elements from the list item but without any progress.
I was also considering if the img can be included in an  tag whereas I can specify the correct height and width.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you are facing an issue with the alignment of the image in your navigation bar. The problem might be related to the default styling of the image or some additional padding/margin applied to the img element.

To fix the alignment issue, you can try the following steps:

Wrap the img tag in an anchor () tag, just like the first social icon. This will allow you to specify the correct height, width, and other styling properties for the image.

```html
<li class='c-nav__item c-nav__item--social'>
  <a href='https://jonasasihlen.medium.com/' title='Medium' target='_blank' rel='noopener'>
    <img src='https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5968/5968906.png' width="20" alt='Medium'>
  </a>
</li>
```

Apply CSS styles to the img element to remove any unwanted padding or margins. You can set the display property to block to ensure it behaves like a block-level element.

```css
.c-nav__item--social img {
  display: block;

}
```

If necessary, you can use the vertical-align property to adjust the vertical alignment of the image.

```css
    
.c-nav__item--social img {
  vertical-align: middle; /* You can experiment with different values like 'top', 'bottom', etc. */
}
```

With these changes, the image should be properly aligned within the navigation bar, and the "jumping" issue should be resolved.

Remember to adjust the CSS class names if needed to match your specific HTML structure. Additionally, you can experiment with the vertical-align property to find the best alignment for your design

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. That made the trick! I updated to display: inline-block and now the img icon is on its place :)